# Java - parsing string to xml output - #text

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to convert a xml `String` to a xml `document`:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
DocumentBuilder builder;  
    try  {  
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
        Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlString ) ) );
         NodeList firstEle = document.getElementsByTagName("eMail");
        for(int i = 0; i < firstEle.getLength();i++){
           Node node = firstEle.item(i); //email
           System.out.println("\ncurrent element : " + node.getNodeName()); //print email
           NodeList allEmailChilds = node.getChildNodes();
           System.out.print("num of child nodes : " + allEmailChilds.getLength());//print 47
           for(int j = 0 ; j<allEmailChilds.getLength(); j++){
               Node inMail = allEmailChilds.item(j);    
               System.out.print("\n");
               System.out.print("email element - " + inMail.getNodeName()); //prints #text

               System.out.print("email value - " + inMail.getTextContent()); //prints empty line
           }
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

Somone knows why it print `#text` instaed of the `nodeName`? I could not found the answer to that anywhere, here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eMail>
  <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
   //more elemnts.....
</eMail>
```

Also when trying to get the node type :

```
   if(inMail.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
      System.out.print("ele node"); // never prints 
   }
```

Never gets printed.

Comment: `#text` is the node name of pure text, what stands _between_ start and end tag ("Tove"). Mind that one can have more than one #text between start and end tag ("To"). Note that `node` could have been cast to `org.w3c.Element` as those are tags.

Comment: OK, thanks, I think that the object of the element is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below code:

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try
        {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(
                    "<eMail><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></eMail> ")));
            NodeList firstEle = document.getElementsByTagName("eMail");
            for (int i = 0; i < firstEle.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node node = firstEle.item(i); // email
                System.out.println("\ncurrent element : " + node.getNodeName()); // print email
                NodeList allEmailChilds = node.getChildNodes();
                System.out.print("num of child nodes : " + allEmailChilds.getLength());// print 47
                for (int j = 0; j < allEmailChilds.getLength(); j++)
                {
                    Node inMail = allEmailChilds.item(j);
                    System.out.print("email element - " + inMail.getNodeName()); // prints #text

                    System.out.print("email value - " + inMail.getTextContent()); // prints empty line
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

> current element : eMail num of child nodes : 4email element - toemail
>   value - Toveemail element - fromemail value - Janiemail element -
>   headingemail value - Reminderemail element - bodyemail value - Don't
>   forget me this weekend!

Comment: Works great, Thanks!